# Rxjs filter operator not working with Angular2 Observable

Tags: http, filter, angular, rxjs, observable

In this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9V8ASsmsbbbhsuD3MtaD?p=preview)
I am trying to employ a filter operator on angular2 observable (Rxjs) inside class member.service.ts. The observable is fetched with an http request, which I process as follows:

```
  getMembers (): Observable<Member[]> {
    var one = this.http.get(this.memberUrl)
    .map( this.extractData )
    //.filter(x => x.type==='member')
   return one
 }
```

My question is: Why would the list not render when I uncomment the line with the filter (please view the in-memory-data.service.ts) ? In my opinion the observable is in an object state after the map operator, and does not have a type property. not sure though!.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your observable is a single item that is an array. It's not an observable of the items within that array. `x` in your filter function: `x=> x.type ==="member"` is an array, so `x.type` doesn't exist. In order to accomplish what you want, you need to iterate over that array:

```
getMembers (): Observable<Member[]> {
    var one = this.http.get(this.memberUrl)
                    .map( this.extractData )
                    .map(memberArray => {
                        return memberArray.filter(x=> x.type === "member")
                    })
    return one
  }
```